# Shorter way to write multiple similar @font-face rules

Tags: css, font-face, shorthand

I have many `@font-face` rules inside a `CSS` file that all have **one template**. This is their **template**:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:FontName; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
    src:    local('FontName'),
            url('http://fonts.example.com/FontName.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('http://fonts.example.com/FontName.woff') format('woff'),
            url('http://fonts.example.com/FontName.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and the `FontName` is different per each font.

Is there a shorter way to write these rules? (Instead of writing them serially in the file.)

---

A sample part of the file is:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:IRLotus; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
    src:    local('IRLotus'),
            url('http://fonts.e900.ir/IRLotus.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('http://fonts.e900.ir/IRLotus.woff') format('woff'),
            url('http://fonts.e900.ir/IRLotus.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family:IRNazanin; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
    src:    local('IRNazanin'),
            url('http://fonts.e900.ir/IRNazanin.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('http://fonts.e900.ir/IRNazanin.woff') format('woff'),
            url('http://fonts.e900.ir/IRNazanin.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family:IRRoya; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
    src:    local('IRRoya'),
            url('http://fonts.e900.ir/IRRoya.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('http://fonts.e900.ir/IRRoya.woff') format('woff'),
            url('http://fonts.e900.ir/IRRoya.ttf') format('truetype');
}
/* 
    And so on ...
*/
```

I searched for a solution, but not found.

Comment: Not without using LESS or SASS / SCSS.

Comment: If you use SASS you could use: https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/d0460e5c2d5d7f9bc5e6